# Factorization of polynomial in multiple variables by a root

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and consider the polynomial ring in $n$ variables $A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Let $f\in A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. If we have that  $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$ for $a_i\in A$, then I was wondering, if it's true, that we can factorize $f$ as $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=b_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)(x_1-a_1)+\ldots+b_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)(x_n-a_n)$ for $b_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

Comment: The maximal ideal at a point is generated by the linear terms you describe, so yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k$ is a field and $p$ is a point, then the set of all polynomials of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which vanish at $p$ form a maximal ideal, sometimes called $m_p$.  With a little work, one can show that 
$$
m_p=\langle x_1-p_1,x_2-p_2,\dots,x_n-p_n \rangle.
$$
In your case (if $A$ is a field), then you're starting with a polynomial in $m_p$, and since $m_p$ is generated by the linear terms $x_i-p_i$, there is a representation as you describe.

If $A$ is not a field in your case, but a more general ring, then some of these facts break down (e.g., consider the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

For general rings, if you write $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ as $x_1f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)+g_1(x_2,\dots,x_n)$, then
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_n)-f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)(x_1-p_1)=p_1f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)+g_2(x_2,\dots,x_n),
$$
which has a lower degree in $x_1$.  By continuing in this way, you can subtract all $x_1$ terms, then the $x_2$ terms, and so on.  Therefore, we may write
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_n)-h(x_1,\dots,x_n)=c
$$
where $h\in \langle x_1-p_1,\dots,x_n-p_n\rangle$ and $c\in A$.  By substituting $p$ into this equation, the LHS vanishes, so $c=0$.  Hence $f$ can be written as you describe.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $
f(x_1,\dots,x_n)-f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)(x_1-p_1)=p_1f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)+g_1(x_2,\dots,x_n)
$?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if I understand how the process works - how do we subtract the $x_2$ term?

Comment: The index has been corrected, thanks.  Can you get down to the case where $x_1$ is eliminated?

Comment: No I'm not quiet sure if I understand from where or what we should subtract something? What would be the next step in the process?

Comment: Repeat the procedure on $f_1$, perhaps you could provide an example.

Comment: So I guess we write $f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1f_2(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+g_1(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ for some $f_2$, whereas $f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-f_2(x_1,\ldots,x_n)(x_1-p_1)=p_1f_2(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+g_1(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. And so by substituting into the first equation and continue this way, until we have done it say $k$ times (if the highest power of $x_1$ is $k$) to get $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f_k(x_1-p_1)^k$?

Comment: Meant $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)(x_1-p_1)^k$ for some $f_k$. How would we then proceed for the $x_2$ terms?

Comment: Use $(x_2-p_2)$ on the remainder.

Comment: You would have $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum h_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)(x_1-p_1)^i+g(x_2,\dots,x_n)$.  Then continue on $g$.